# OpenCL bincount

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I am trying to implement a bincount operation in OpenCL which allocates an output buffer and uses indices from x to accumulate some weights at the same index (assume that `num_bins == max(x)`). This is equivalent to the following python code:

```
out = np.zeros_like(num_bins)
for i in range(len(x)):
    out[x[i]] += weight[i]
return out
```

What I have is the following:

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
__kernel void bincount(__global int *res_g, __global const int* x_g, __global const int* weight_g)
{
  int gid = get_global_id(0);
  res_g[x_g[gid]] += weight_g[gid];
}
""").build()

# test
x = np.arange(5, dtype=np.int32).repeat(2) # [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
x_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, cl.mem_flags.READ_WRITE | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=x)

weight = np.arange(10, dtype=np.int32) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
weight_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, cl.mem_flags.READ_WRITE | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=weight)

res_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, cl.mem_flags.READ_WRITE, 4 * 5)

prg.bincount(queue, [10], None, res_g, x_g, weight_g)

# transfer back to cpu
res_np = np.empty(5).astype(np.int32)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, res_np, res_g)
```

Output in `res_np`:

```
array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], dtype=int32)
```

Expected output:

```
array([1, 5, 9, 13, 17], dtype=int32)
```

How do I accumulate the elements that are indexed more than once?

**EDIT**

The above is a contrived example, in my real-world application `x` will be indices from a sliding window algorithm:

```
x = np.array([ 0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  6,  8,  9, 10,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  9, 10,
              11,  4,  5,  6,  8,  9, 10, 12, 13, 14,  5,  6,  7,  9, 10, 11, 13,
              14, 15,  8,  9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18,  9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15,
              17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26,
              27, 29, 30, 31, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 32, 33, 34, 25, 26, 27, 29,
              30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 28, 29, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 38, 29, 30, 31,
              33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39], dtype=np.int32)

weight = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                   0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
                   0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                   1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                   0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=np.int32)
```

There is a pattern which becomes more apparent when reshaping `x` to `(2,3,2,3,3)`. But I am having a hard time figuring out how the approach given by @doqtor can be used here and especially if it is easy enough to generalize.

The expected output is:

```
array([1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that OpenCL buffer to which weights are accumulated is not initialized (zeroed). Fixing that:

```
res_np = np.zeros(5).astype(np.int32)
res_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, cl.mem_flags.WRITE_ONLY | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=res_np)

prg.bincount(queue, [10], None, res_g, x_g, weight_g)

# transfer back to cpu
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, res_np, res_g)
```

Returns correct results: `[ 1  5  9 13 17]`

====== Update ==========

As @Kevin noticed there is race condition here too. If there is any pattern it could be addressed this way without using synchronization, for example processing every 2 elements by 1 work item:

```
__kernel void bincount(__global int *res_g, __global const int* x_g, __global const int* weight_g)
{
  int gid = get_global_id(0);
  for(int x = gid*2; x < gid*2+2; ++x)
      res_g[x_g[x]] += weight_g[x];
}
```

Then schedule 5 work items:

```
prg.bincount(queue, [5], None, res_g, x_g, weight_g)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same wrong result. I should be running OpenCL 3.0.

Comment: The problem is trivial and I certainly doubt version of OpenCL matters here. Make sure last 5 non-empty lines are replaced with the code from the answer.

Comment: I made sure the output buffer was zero-initialized and still the same.

Comment: I am not sure but I think the whole problem has to do with work-item synchronization. I am launching 10 threads for each element in ```x```, but there might be a conflict when two threads are writing to the same index and causing the "slowest" thread to overwrite?

Comment: Yep, you are right, there is race condition here. For this particular example you could make each 2 elements run by one work item.

Comment: This is a good solution for this particular example. I made an edit to my post with one of my real-world examples. I was looking for a generalized solution, but maybe this deserves a new question of its own. I'll accept this answer but you are welcome to submit another answer for my revised post.

Comment: @Kevin I'd suggest making another question for real world example.